# OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support on MacOS

Tags: c++

I've have my motion detection program written in C++, running correctly in Linux.
Just copy and test in MacOS, but got the error "OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11":

```
In file included from video_process.cpp:1:
In file included from ./video_process.h:17:
In file included from ./yolov4.h:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc.hpp:46:
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:52:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvdef.h:732:4: error: "OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support"
  error "OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support"
   ^
In file included from video_process.cpp:1:
In file included from ./video_process.h:17:
In file included from ./yolov4.h:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc.hpp:46:
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54:
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:58:
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:81:
```

I have -std=c++11 in my Makefile, and the code is working correctly in Linux.
What could cause this problem on MacOS?..

Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -w -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/lib -I/usr/include/mysql `pkg-config --cflags opencv4` -pthread
LIBS = -L/usr/local/lib/mysql `pkg-config --libs opencv4` -lmysqlclient
OBJS = video_process.o motion_background_diff.o yolov4.o preprocess.o

TARGET = motion_detection

$(TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```

Comment: whats the version of your gcc?  (the one running in your mac of course)

Comment: g++ --version
g++ (Homebrew GCC 11.3.0_1) 11.3.0
gcc --version
gcc (Homebrew GCC 11.3.0_1) 11.3.0

Comment: can you post the whole output of a single call to gcc? eg: `make video_process.o`

Comment: That left me with the same output :(

Comment: I'm sorry what I meant was the actual invocation to GCC (we cannot se what's being executed there)